# postgresql query returned more than one row Django/heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

This is working on local, I print it and it all looks fine to me but when I push to heroku which is running postgres, it gives me this error `more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`.
Here's what I have:

```
locations = UserLocations.objects.filter(album =album) 
wish = UserWishList.objects.filter(traveler = people).values_list('place', flat=True)
wish_places =  UserLocations.objects.filter(id__in = wish)
merge = locations | UserLocations.objects.filter(id__in = wish)
```

and it's error when I'm retrieving merge. I tried doing `distinct()`, that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running different versions of Django in those servers. That happened to me when I upgraded to Django 1.10 if I recall correctly.

I would guess that you'll solve the problem if you filter wish with '__in=people'

Comment: unfortunately, didn't work. I really hope it's not different django version. I didn't even upgrade on either end

Comment: Could you print album and people? One of those parameters has to have more than one element

Comment: Well they are instances, so wouldn't it have more than one element? Ah is it people they are many relationships? But I dont understand why it works on local.